# Time Machine on Mac

Tags: mac, time-machine, recovery

Does the `Time Machine` program backup system plus data ?

Will is restore the computer exactly to what is was including both system and data (ie. emails, photos, documents) ?

Comment: I have to enter min 15 charters to answer YES :)

Answer (score 2):

Time Machine backs up all content, excluding data you've excluded in the Time Machine preferences pane, most system caches/temporary files, and any data listed in the `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist`'s ExcludeByPath key.

When you restore from a Time Machine backup, all data is as it was when the last backup was performed. A perfect replica, from the user's side.

Certain Microsoft Office products may notice a change if you restore your Time Machine backup to another computer/hard drive, as it uses the hard drive's serial number to validate software authenticity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will create an exact copy of what is on your hard drive at that time, including every little email or conversation stored.